# Performance issue with range.calculate()

Tags: excel, vba

I met an issue when I use range.calculate() in VBA.
The following is situation:

- 32bit Excel 2010 version; Windows 7
- 50K records as input, being processed one by one;
- When running, excel uses ~400M memory;
- Links are built in excel tab; the links among cells don't follow from left to right, top to down rule. there are many back and forth links.
- call worksheet.range.calculate() in VBA for the calculations in the cells;

Code:

```
...
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Worksheets("Curve").Range("A1:BO600").Calculate
...
```

Problem:

- Based on Microsoft instruction, Range.Calculate in Excel 2010 resolves the dependencies within the range being calculated. But based on my debugging, Range.calculate() calculates cells from left to right and top to bottom, ignoring all dependencies, just as excel 2000 version. Then the calculation of next record will use the result of the previous one (stored in excel cells now) rather than the refreshed result of its own record since the depended cells may have not been calculated.
- It doesn't recur every time when I run my models. I met this issue 2 months ago, after restarted my PC with applying some windows updates automatically, the issue disappeared and Range.Calculate() works as expected in the past 2 months. Now the issue comes back and I could not get rid of it with PC shutdown, or excel closing.
- More importantly, if I switch to worksheet.calculcate(), the issue has gone but the running takes more time.

Any clue on this problem? Thanks a lot in advance.

Leal

Comment: @charleswilliams pinging the expert. :)

Comment: Hi, Brettdj (@brettdj ), I must miss your comment a week ago. I am new to this forum. Do you suggest me to contact charleswilliams? I could not find charleswilliams in the forum. Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks a lot. --Leal